# How do I merge 2 branches created at the same time off of main, back into main without creating a conflict

Tags: clearcase

[image]

On this example, how are merges back to “main” from “windows” and “test” branches normally handled (red lines)?

For instance, developer under “windows” branch fixes a bug by setting A=1, and then  tests the fix under “windows” and calls it “done”, so he merges “windows” back to “main” as “main/8”  that’s not a problem thus far.

But then,  say that developer under “test” branch changes A to “A=0” to fix the bug he is working on.

What happens when  “test/4” is merged back to “main”?

Now “main/9” shows “A=0”, overwriting the fix done by “windows/1”.

Then say that the developer who worked on the fix under “windows” now needs to work on another fix and creates “windows_2”.  He will be thinking that A is still “A=1”, because that’s how he left it.  The developer might go through a painful process to discover that now “A=0”.

How are these types of changes handled, so changes do not get reversed from one merge to the next when branches are created in parallel from the main “trunk”?

Any info will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens when “`test/4`” is merged back to “main”?

This is a non-trivial merge, because the*same* line for "`A=`" has been modified *twice*, compared with the common ancestor. This is a clear conflict during the merge, and it won't be an automatic one.

So the developer merging back `test` branch will have to choose between `test` and `windows` line, and hopefully, will check with the developer from the `windows` branch.

From the [merge page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_merge_file_dir.htm):

> When two or more contributors differ from the base contributor, Diff Merge detects the conflict, and prompts you to resolve it. It displays all contributor differences and you can accept or reject each one.

```
          [changed 10]            |          [changed to 10 file 2]---
A;                                | A=1;
                                 -|-
          [changed 10]            |          [changed to 10 file 3]---
A;                                | A=0
                                  |-
Do you want the CHANGE made in file 2? [yes] 
no  
Do you want the CHANGE made in file 3? [yes] 
yes
Applying CHANGE from file 3 [line 10]
============
```

---

But the true answer is **communication**: if the *same* file needs modifications (especially in the *same* lines), there should be some way of managing and coordinating those types of development efforts.

ClearCase also proposed locks on checkout (`cleartool checkout -reserved`) which would prevent `test` to be checked out while `windows` version is checked out. That can also prompt the developer on `test` to check with his/her colleague, and be aware of the nature of the fix being done.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I'm starting to see where the term "merge hell" is coming from :=|